# ¿Cómo representar porcentajes gráficamente?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

Tengo este dataframe:

```
sample_size     subject     very    not_at_all
0   2202    concern-economy     19.00   11.00
1   2202    concern-economy     26.00   7.00
2   1500    concern-infected    13.00   18.00
3   2200    concern-economy     23.00   9.00
4   1000    concern-infected    11.00   20.00
5   1500    concern-infected    11.00   22.00
9   1500    concern-infected    10.00   19.00
10  1500    concern-infected    10.00   20.00
```

Donde:

- sample_size es el total de las personas entrevistadas por una entrevista
- subject es la materia de la entrevista
- Las columnas very y not_at_all están en tanto por ciento respecto la respuesta en la población (sample_size) de cada entrevista

Quiero obtener un gráfico que represente cuál es el porcentaje de gente en la matèria (subject) de la entrevista relacionada con "concern_economy" está very (concern, preocupación) y cuánta está not_at_all (concern, preocupación)

He llegado hasta aquí:

```
concern_polls[(concern_polls.subject == "concern-economy")][['very_total','not_at_all_total']].sum().plot.bar(rot=0)
```

Pero de esta manera estoy sumando todos los valores de las columnas "very" y "not_at_all" mientras lo que me gustaría es representar el porcentaje total de "very" concerned y "not_at_all" concerned sobre el  total de "sample_size"

Entonces he creado otras columnas con números totales:

```
concern_polls["very_total"] =  ((concern_polls.very*concern_polls.sample_size) / 100) 
concern_polls["not_at_all_total"] = ((concern_polls.not_at_all*concern_polls.sample_size) / 100)
```

que sumado los totales:

```
concern_polls[(concern_polls.subject == "concern-economy" )][['sample_size','very_total','not_at_all_total']].sum()
```

y tengo este resultado:

```
sample_size         1060962.00
very_total           654472.84
not_at_all_total      28491.60
```

Ahora me gustaría representar los resultados en porcentajes sobre sample_size gráficamente con un bar plot o bien pie plot, **pero estoy segura que hay una manera más efectiva de hacerlo.**

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto? (:

Comment: Lee [ask]: muestra qué has intentado hasta el momento. Hay muchos tipos de gráficos.

Comment: quieres saber que porcentaje es `not_at_all` de `sample_size` y eso representarlo en una grefica?

Comment: los valores de not_at_all son porcentajes de sample_size, me gustaría representar gráficamente el porcentaje total de not_at_all sobre el total de  sample_size

Comment: ok, quieres sumar sus valores y representarlos en una grafica, pero... en que tipo de grafica?

Comment: en un simple bar plot sería lo mejor @Christian (:  ¿Pero puedo sumar los valores de la columna not_at_all, si son porcentajes? Es decir, teniendo en cuenta la primera fila:  11% de sample_size  está  "not_at_all" concerned. Mi pregunta cuales el el porcentaje total de "not_at_all" concerned.

Comment: si lo puedes hacer, pues son numero enteros, si fuese un string `11%` ahi tendriamos un problema

Comment: @Christian pero suma de porcentajes (aunque sean números) de diferentes poblaciones, no será representativa, como porcentaje de suma total de sample_size , o me estoy perdiendo algo de matemática básica?

Comment: Pues nop, estas bien, hice algo pero no se si es lo que quieres